# Confused by how the rvalue reference vector::push_back function increases effciency

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, move, rvalue-reference

From the cppreference.com, I found a simple example about using the std::move:

```
std::string str = "Hello";
std::vector<std::string> v;

// uses the push_back(const T&) overload, which means 
// we'll incur the cost of copying str
v.push_back(str);                                    // First push_back
std::cout << "After copy, str is \"" << str << "\"\n";

// uses the rvalue reference push_back(T&&) overload, 
// which means no strings will be copied; instead, the contents
// of str will be moved into the vector.  This is less
// expensive, but also means str might now be empty.
v.push_back(std::move(str));                        // Second push_back
```

The comment says that string copy was avoided.

The first push_back will call: `void push_back(const value_type& _Val)`

The second push_back will call: `void push_back(value_type&& _Val)`

I checked the implementation code of the two functions:

```
void push_back(const value_type& _Val)
    {   // insert element at end
    if (_Inside(_STD addressof(_Val)))
        {   // push back an element
        size_type _Idx = _STD addressof(_Val) - _Unfancy(this->_Myfirst());
        if (this->_Mylast() == this->_Myend())
            _Reserve(1);
        _Orphan_range(this->_Mylast(), this->_Mylast());
        this->_Getal().construct(_Unfancy(this->_Mylast()),
            this->_Myfirst()[_Idx]);
        ++this->_Mylast();
        }
    else
        {   // push back a non-element
        if (this->_Mylast() == this->_Myend())
            _Reserve(1);
        _Orphan_range(this->_Mylast(), this->_Mylast());
        this->_Getal().construct(_Unfancy(this->_Mylast()),
            _Val);
        ++this->_Mylast();
        }
    }
```

and

```
void push_back(value_type&& _Val)
    {   // insert by moving into element at end
    if (_Inside(_STD addressof(_Val)))
        {   // push back an element
        size_type _Idx = _STD addressof(_Val) - _Unfancy(this->_Myfirst());
        if (this->_Mylast() == this->_Myend())
            _Reserve(1);
        _Orphan_range(this->_Mylast(), this->_Mylast());
        this->_Getal().construct(_Unfancy(this->_Mylast()),
            _STD forward<value_type>(this->_Myfirst()[_Idx]));
        ++this->_Mylast();
        }
    else
        {   // push back a non-element
        if (this->_Mylast() == this->_Myend())
            _Reserve(1);
        _Orphan_range(this->_Mylast(), this->_Mylast());
        this->_Getal().construct(_Unfancy(this->_Mylast()),
            _STD forward<value_type>(_Val));
        ++this->_Mylast();
        }
    }
```

So, according to my understanding, both first push_back (`v.push_back(str);`) and second push_back (`v.push_back(std::move(str));`) will trigger the vector to construct a `std::string` type variable and attach it to the vector.

So, actually in both push_back calls, string was not copied. And, for both push_back, the expense are the same, because both calls basically do the same thing except the second push_back will make the `str` input to be empty.

As for the efficiency, the only difference I can think of is that the second push_back will not call the delete []cstring; in the destructor of std::string which makes the second push_back call a little bit more efficient.

Not sure if my understanding is correct. Thanks a lot!

Comment: With the `const T&` override the content of the original string must be copied into the container. Any interpretation of the implementation that concludes that the content isn't copied is incorrect.

Comment: I think you're missing to *move* capability the rref brings to the constructed object. Sure a new object is constructed in the container, but that object can reap its *guts* from two places: a copy, or a *move*. The latter will leave the object referenced by `_Val` a mere shell (often literally) of what it once was.

Comment: The real move optimization is happening in [`std::string::string(string&&)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), not in the vector directly. A string has to be constructed either way, but the rvalue overload of `push_back()` allows the string to be *move-constructed* instead of *copy-constructed*.

Comment: "*So, actually in both push_back calls, string was not copied.*" What do you think is happening in `this->_Getal().construct(_Unfancy(this->_Mylast()), _Val)`? When you construct a new `T` with an lvalue reference to an existing `T`, that's called *copying*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is here:

```
    this->_Getal().construct(_Unfancy(this->_Mylast()),
        _STD forward<value_type>(_Val));
```

vs

```
    this->_Getal().construct(_Unfancy(this->_Mylast()),
        _Val);
```

Now that `forward<value_type>` in effect calls `std::move` on the `std::string`.

In one case, we construct a `std::string` by `std::string const&`, in the other by a `std::string &&`.

So to see the difference, we have to examine what those two different constructors do.

`std::string` is usually implemented with the SBO (small buffer optimization).  If the string is short (a dozen or so characters), the string is stored *within* the `std::string`.

If it is longer, instead the `std::string` stores a pointer to it.

If you have SBO active, both move and copy copy the bytes over.  Move may then clear the source.

`std::string(std::string const&)` in the case of non-SBO does an allocation and duplicates the buffer containing the characters.

`std::string(std::string &&)` in the case of non-SBO moves the pointer over to the destination object, and empties the source object.  No memory allocation occurs, and zero bytes are copied.

This is what the `push_back(&&)` overload provides.

Answer (score 3):

Short of optimizations like "Small String", `std::basic_string` contains what is basically a pointer to dynamically allocated area for the characters in the string.  It is this copy that's avoided because a moved-to can just steal the moved-from's pointer rather than allocate its own and copy the data.

Comment: According to my understanding, the elements in a vector should be in continuous memory space. Suppose only pointers were copied, if we have multiple push_back with rvalues and those rvalues are at separate memory locations, then the new vector will not hold its elements in a continuous memory space.

Comment: Moreover, just as @Nicol Bolas said, the "copings "are there for construction.

Comment: @lightrek Just because the `std::string` objects in `v` are in continuous memory space, doesn't mean the `char`s they conceptually contain are in continuous memory space.

Comment: @lightrek - aschepler said it.  You have to consider pointers as values.  You can store pointers in a vector.  Those pointers will be in contiguous memory, but what they point to will not be.  Vector in fact cannot store string data of several strings in contiguous memory.  Strings have a dynamic size that can grow.  Vector has no way of knowing how, when...etc.  It doesn't know how to allocate such a thing.